# WebSphere application server,listener goes down when error is there MQueue message?

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

I am using MQ server for messaging in WebSphere application server 8.5.23. I want the lister to be disabled after 3 attempts of receiving message from MQ server when error is there in the message.

I did not find any such option

Comment: What does the application currently do when there is an error. Is this an abend situation? Do the application backout the message? Please elaborate a little more on details such as there by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set maximum retries on the listener port to 3. If you do this you need to make sure that the backout threshold on the queue is set higher than 3 or MQ will move it to the dead letter queue and WebSphere won’t know.

The documentation for this is [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=settings-listener-port)